# Why I get "ambiguous" compile error overloading methods like f(int... arg) and f(Integer... arg)?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Why I get "ambiguous" compile error overloading methods like `void f(int... arg)` and `void f(Integer... arg)` ?

I know that according to JLS argument resolution is done in three steps (proceeding to next step only if previous step yielded no match):

1. primitive (and its widening if exact match fails)
2. boxing (and reference widening if exact match fails)
3. varargs (doing steps 1 and 2 but for varargs)

Question 1: So when it comes to third step (varargs), it tries both to convert to vararg using steps 1 and step 2 (now it tries both equally, with no precedence) and if there can be 2 signatures it is ambiguous. I thought vararg checking should stop at int... and never try boxing after having a match at step 1.

Question 2: `void f(int arg)` and `void f(long arg)` never give "umbiguous" error, so within one step (step 1 here) "exact match" and "widening" never compete - having exact match compiler never tries to do widening (unlkike third vararg step when after matching primitive vararg it also tries boxing and matching boxed vararg)